# upload a file to s3 after script end/crashes: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sigint, atexit

I need to upload a file to s3 no matter how a script end/interrupts.

I have done:

```
import atexit
import signal
atexit.register(exit_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_handler)
def exit_handler():
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_client.upload_file(file,bucket, file)
```

But when sending CTRL+C I get:

```
File "/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 474, in submit
    future = ExecutorFuture(self._executor.submit(task))
  File "/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 169, in submit
    raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after '
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown
```

Comment: The main process could create a `multiprocessing.Process` which does the actual work while the main process watches if the worker process is still alive. As soon as the worker terminates, the main process uploads the file.

Comment: sounds like an answer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main process could create a [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions) (worker process) which does the actual work.

The main process watches if the worker process is still alive using `join()`, `is_alive()` or the `sentinel` attribute.

As soon as the worker terminates, the main process can upload the file.